# WCF service stops processing requests after some time

Tags: rest, wcf, httpclient

we have a WCF service, that we recently changed from

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

to

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

in order to improve performance.

Since then it runs faster, but testing with 3 clients using following code:

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient { Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan };
    private static string uri= $"http://localhost:8080/WcfService/DoSomething";


static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
       for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
       {
                var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, GetSomeData());
       }
    }
```

brings the following errors:

[image]

translated:

> An attempt was made to access a network connection that does not exist

Not sure how to find and fix the problem. Would be grateful for any assistance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not possible to answer without more information. That behavior is not just due to the WCF configuration. It could due to how your service handles resources (memory and perhaps cpu). To me it sounds like resource starvation.

Monitor resources and GC stats when you run your test. Could also be haning on outgoing http connections for e.g.

Comment: It may be the limitation of Concurrent processing in IIS. try to configure the ConcurrencyMode of WCF.
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode =InstanceContextMode.Single,ConcurrencyMode =ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
And the throttling.
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentInstances="100" maxConcurrentSessions="10000"/>

Comment: For details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode?view=netframework-4.8
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-servicethrottlingbehavior-to-control-wcf-service-performance

Comment: memory and cpu are definitely not the problem, and maximal number of concurrent IIS requests is way higher than the total number of requests i make in my tests (4294967295 vs 300000). There must be something else that is causing this.